# How do I accept an output parameter array and a scalar in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a function where I want to check if a path exists, and if it does, add that to an array. Here's what I tried:

```
# If a path exists, adds the canonical version of that path to an array
sub AddPathCandidate {
    my (@$target, $path) = $_;
    die ('path needed') unless defined($path);
    $path = File::Spec->canonpath($path);
    if (-e $path) {
        push(@{$target}, $path);
    }
}
```

where the caller looks like:

```
my @exampleDirs = ();
AddPathCandidate(\@exampleDirs, $inDir . 'a');
AddPathCandidate(\@exampleDirs, $inDir . "../b/a/$arch");
AddPathCandidate(\@exampleDirs, $inDir . "../../b/a/$arch");
```

But the "die" statement always executes; the second parameter of AddPathCandidate isn't getting through somehow.

Is what I'm trying to do here even possible or is there some more "perl-ish way" to accomplish this?

Comment: @toolic: Also, the copy of perl I "get" to use is ancient 5.6, so it's possible they fixed this since then.

Comment: @BillyONeal Holy crap, Perl 5.6 is old enough to drive in some countries!

Comment: @duskwuff: Yeah. Our test harness is _OLD_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare the variable as `$target` when unpacking your arguments, and unpack from `@_`:

```
my ($target, $path) = @_;
    ^                 ^^
```

Comment: So one double facepalm typo, and one perl just being strange. Got it, thanks!

Comment: What was the Perl being strange bit?

Comment: @Grant: Declaring the thing you want to be an array as a scalar.

Comment: @BillyONeal That's because the "thing" is not an array, it's a reference. And all references are scalars.

Comment: @BillyONeal If you really want to understand references [Mark's very short tutorial about references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) is an excellent place to start.